# Do testability and falsifiability have statistical definitions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, terminology, definition, psychology, philosophical

*Psychology: the Core Concepts* says

> Psychology  differs  from  the  pseudosciences  in  that  it  employs
> the scientific method to test its ideas empirically.  The scientific
> method  relies on testable theories and falsifiable hypotheses.

Do testability and   falsifiability    have statistical definitions? If not, what do they mean roughly, and how are they related and different?

Are theory and hypothesis  the same concepts?

Answer (score 16):

Testability and falsifiability are general ideas that are discussed at length in the philosophy of science, but they manifest in statistics and aspects of these concepts can be framed in statistical or probabilistic terms.  It is useful to have a broad understanding of the philosophy of science and its historical development to understand these concepts, but it is also useful to see how they arise in the context of probability and statistics.  Below we examine the latter.

##### The principle of "falsifiability" is a consequence of the law of total probability

The principle of falsifiability means that in a valid experimental situation relating to a hypothesis, there must be at least one possible outcome that would count as evidence *against* the hypothesis; if there is not, then the experiment cannot ever be considered to give evidence *in favour* of the hypothesis.  This principle is built into probability theory via the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), and it occurs in Bayesian reasoning.  This rule of probability ensures that *if there can be confirmatory evidence for a hypothesis, then it must also be possible for there to be disconfirmatory evidence for that same hypothesis*.  This property of probability theory is captured in the following simple theorem.

> **Theorem (Principle of falsifiability for countable space):** Consider a hypothesis $H$ and suppose we have a partition of the sample space $\mathscr{E}$ composed of a countable number of events.  Suppose that there is at least one piece of confirmatory evidence $E \in \mathscr{E}$ that is in favour of the hypothesis ---i.e., a piece of evidence such that:
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(H|E) > \mathbb{P}(H).$$
>
> Then there must exist at least one event $E' \in \mathscr{E}$ that is disconfirmatory to the hypothesis ---i.e., a piece of evidence such that:
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(H|E') < \mathbb{P}(H).$$
>
> **Proof:** We will use a proof by contradiction.  Suppose ---contra the theorem--- that for all $R \in \mathscr{E}$ we have $\mathbb{P}(H|R) \geqslant \mathbb{P}(H)$.  Using the law of total probability, we then have:
>
> $$\begin{align}
> \mathbb{P}(H)
> &= \sum_{R} \mathbb{P}(H|R) \mathbb{P}(R) \\[6pt]
> &= \bigg[ \mathbb{P}(H|E) \mathbb{P}(E) + {\sum_{R \neq E} \mathbb{P}(H|R) \mathbb{P}(R)} \bigg] \\[6pt]
> &\geqslant \bigg[ \mathbb{P}(H|E) \mathbb{P}(E) + {\sum_{R \neq E} \mathbb{P}(H) \mathbb{P}(R)} \bigg] \\[6pt]
> &> \bigg[ \mathbb{P}(H) \mathbb{P}(E) + {\sum_{R \neq E} \mathbb{P}(H) \mathbb{P}(R)} \bigg] \\[6pt]
> &= \mathbb{P}(H) \bigg[ \mathbb{P}(E) + {\sum_{R \neq E} \mathbb{P}(R)} \bigg] \\[6pt]
> &= \mathbb{P}(H) {\sum_{R} \mathbb{P}(R)} \\[8pt]
> &= \mathbb{P}(H), \\[6pt]
> \end{align}$$
>
> which is a contradiction.  This establishes the theorem.  $\blacksquare$

If you would like to see an application of this principle within Bayesian reasoning, you might be interested in reading [O'Neill (2014)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43820832) on the famous "doomsday argument".  This paper argues that the doomsday argument is an example of erroneous reasoning in which there is an argument to a foregone conclusion, in contradiction to the proper application of Bayes' rule.  You might also be interested in reading [Kadane et al (1996)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2291741), which talks generally about the notion of "reasoning to a foregone conclusion" (i.e., without the possibility of falsification) and gives sufficient foundational conditions for probabilistic reasoning under which this cannot occur.

##### The principle of "testability" relates to experimental design and other statistical principles

The notion of "testability" means that it is possible to create an experiment that can provide sufficient evidence to test the hypothesis.  This idea therefore forms a part of the field of experimental design, which can be regarded as a subfield of statistics.  Wrapped up in this notion is the determination of the requirements that would be needed to form a valid experiment for a hypothesis, any protocols that need to be applied (e.g., randomisation, blinding, etc.), and how much evidence needs to be accumulated in order to get sufficient evidence on the hypothesis of interest to make an inference at some minimum level of confidence/accuracy.  The last of these is usually determined by making sample size calculations using statistical rules.

Testability can be framed in many different ways, with stronger or weaker requirements for particular contexts.  It is often framed as requiring it to be possible to determine whether the hypothesis is true or false, and in some contexts it might require one to test causal hypothesis, which then imposes additional requirements.  In any case, those are strong notions of testability, but if we are willing to think probabilistically, then a very weak notion of testability would merely require that it is possible to create an experiment that can provide either confirmatory or disconfirmatory evidence to some degree.  This is a lot weaker than some demands for testability but it does provide a potential starting point.

If we are willing accept a very weak notion of testability then this occurs when it is possible to construct an experiment where the evidence can shift our posterior belief away from our prior belief under some observable evidence.  We have already seen above that if it is possible to see confirmatory evidence then it must also be possible to see disconfirmatory evidence, so a belief-shift either way could potentially occur.  Weak testability would occur so long as the evidence in the experiment is not (statistically) independent of the hypothesis of interest.  If we want to impose a stronger requirement for testability then it might entail having a larger amount of evidence (e.g., a minimal required sample size), or it might require imposing a particular experimental design or experimental protocols.

Comment: Well said.  I'll just add that in most situations decision making is the most applicable approach (and one for which Bayes is tremendously suited).  One can make the needed decision without having hypotheses or discussing falsifiability etc.  Bayesian posterior inference allows one to play the odds, just as we do in everyday life.  Full Bayesian decisions based on maximizing expected utility formalizes and optimizes the process.

Comment: Choosing a personal prior probability of the truth of an hypothesis does not sound like the scientific method to me. Or are you restricting your answer to some form of 'objective' Bayesian approach? (I understand that many Bayesians object to the 'objective' approach.)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147949/discussion-on-answer-by-ben-do-testability-and-falsifiability-have-statistical-d); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: "*[...] all with positive probability*", darn, and here I was hoping to use [negative probability](https://cds.cern.ch/record/154856/files/pre-27827.pdf/)! 

Comment: @Galen: Actually, the assumption is there to rule out events with zero probability, so as to allow me to put the probabilities in the denominator of a fraction.  :)

Answer (score 14):

They don't have statistical *definitions* but statistics may be helpful in showing either.

"Testable" means ... well "can be tested". If (sticking to psychology) is that, say, "In college, men prefer male professors and women prefer female ones" then that is testable because I can (at least in theory) look at a whole bunch of male and female college students and get them to rate male and female professors. This is a case where statistics will be very helpful in doing the test.  On the other hand, if my hypothesis is "every male student dislikes every female professor" then statistics isn't needed. One example is enough.

"Falsifiable" means that there is some possible evidence which would lead me to reject my hypothesis. Maybe statistical, maybe not.

EDIT: In the second paragraph, I mean "reject" in the common language sense, rather than in the sense of statistics (although they could overlap).

Comment: Thanks. Are theory (in logic, e.g. statistical theory) and hypothesis (in statistical testing) the same concept?

Comment: When both "testable" and "falsifiable" are used in statistics, what do they mean in terms of hypothesis testing?

Comment: @Tim "Testable theories" and "falsifiable hypotheses" are broad concepts in science that statistical methods are often used to address. Perhaps your specific questions in your above comments would be better addressed in new questions.

Comment: The last paragraph could do with some claification as "reject" is a jargon term in statistics.  If you reject a hypothesis (e.g. H0) it does not mean that you have shown it to be false (that seems close to the p-value fallacy).  Frequentist approaches cannot assign a probability to the true of a particular hypothesis, which seems to make falsification of a particular hypothesis rather problematic.  Rejecting a hypothesis in an NHST sense is not the same as falsification.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial on the flip side of that coin, though, "falsifiable" is a jargon term in philosophy of science.  It does not generally imply "proven to be false" in the mathematical sense of the term "proof".  I'm not sure how this note fits in here, but I don't think your objection is wholly justified.

Comment: "A theory is to be called 'empirical' or 'falsifiable' if it divides the class of all possible basic statements unambiguously into the following two nonempty subclasses. First, the class of all those basic statements with which it is inconsistent (or which it rules out, or prohibits): we call this the class of the potential falsifiers of the theory; and secondly, the class of those basic statements which it does not contradict (or which it 'permits'). We can put this more briefly by saying: a theory is falsifiable if the class of its potential falsifiers is not empty." --K.Popper

Comment: and a "basic statement": "statements asserting that an observable event is occurring in a certain individual region of space and time" --K.Popper

Comment: @Him indeed, but I had assumed we were talking about the philosophy of science falsifiiability.  I am not sure that there is an everyday meaning of the term which has a substantially different meaning (just not defined as formally).  Jargon terms do make it difficult to define things sometimes, which is somewhat ironic! ;o)

Answer (score 11):

This is meant to add an aspect to the other answers, which have some valuable material.

When talking about "falsification" in statistics, in most cases this isn't the same as logical falsification in the sense that a hypothesis would be logically falsified if something happens that under the hypothesis is *impossible*, so the hypothesis is strictly incompatible with the observed data and must therefore be false (even though philosophy of science teaches that it isn't quite that easy even without taking into account statistical variation, as in many cases something that supposedly refutes a theory/hypothesis can be explained in other ways such as erroneous measurements, or failure of an auxiliary hypothesis that connects the main hypothesis to the data rather than failure of the main hypothesis of interest itself).

In statistics, however, standard models will assign nonzero probability (or at least density) to every potential outcome, be the hypothesis true or not, and this means that any claim that a hypothesis "is falsified by the data" will come with a nonzero error probability, i.e., observed data were just very unlikely but not strictly impossible (regardless of whether we're talking Bayesian or frequentist inference). This also means that if we want to make statements such as "the hypothesis is falsified by the data", this needs to be based on a threshold (how small a probability is small enough to talk of "falsification"), or otherwise we can only make "graded" statements (such as p-value or posterior probability of hypothesis or Bayes factor equal to 0.03), but ultimately an interpretation in words is needed anyway.

Regarding what the hypotheses are, statistical hypotheses are probability models (often parametric with a restrictive specification of parameter values), whereas "research hypotheses" are often informal (in some fields that strongly rely on mathematics, formal research hypotheses are the standard, but in some other fields almost everything is informal). So a research hypothesis needs to be "translated" into a statistical model, and this usually involves model assumptions such as independence or certain distributional shapes that can be doubted (and checked, but only to a limited extent) and may affect the interpretation of any outcome of the statistical analyses. In fact this adds an additional source of uncertainty on top of any uncertainty already modelled by the statistical model.

The question regarding theory vs. hypothesis makes sense regarding the "research hypothesis", but chances are that in different fields and situations connections between what people call "theory" and what people call "research hypothesis" may differ (a research hypothesis may often be a more specified instance/special case of a more general theory); in any case the *statistical hypothesis* will not normally be identical to the research hypothesis let alone the scientific theory of interest, but will come with additional restrictions (and/or add-ons, as the theory to be tested may not involve observational variation, which is modelled by the statistical hypothesis).

This also implies that for any result of a statistical analysis it makes sense to ask: "Could these data have led us to a different conclusion had we chosen another statistical model that is as well compatible with the research hypothesis of interest and - as far as this can be tested - the data?"

Another uncomfortable implication is that if many statistical hypothesis are up for "falsification" at a certain probability standard, the probability that an error ("statistically falsifying" a hypothesis that is in fact true) occurs can become quite large, as the probability that *one out of many (falsification) events* obtains can be quite large even if the probability for every single such event is very small (referred to as the problem of multiple testing in statistics).

Comment: "This also implies that for any result of a statistical analysis it makes sense to ask: "Could these data have led us to a different conclusion had we chosen another statistical model that is as well compatible with the research hypothesis of interest and - as far as this can be tested - the data?" ...." Such a question would seem to be an unsurmoutable challenge for a Bayesian, given the flexibility provided by the choices for a prior.

Comment: @GrahamBornholt There won't be an exhaustive answer to that question, neither for frequentists, but this doesn't mean that we shouldn't even start asking (some sensitivity analysis is better than none).

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 10):

These are important concepts that are in many ways more fundamental than statistics, they are about philosophy of science. I know only a little about this, so what follows is mainly a summary of my thinking and not an expert answer.

*Theories* are organising frameworks that contain several related ideas. A single theory can lead to or contain several *hypotheses*. A hypothesis is much more specific: it is an explanation for a phenomenon that includes a specific mechanism. Note that these are  *research* or *scientific hypotheses*, not the *statistical hypotheses* that we frame in our models<sup>1</sup>. A research or scientific hypothesis has to be translated into a statistical hypothesis to be amenable to quantitative analysis (or perhaps 'quantitative falsification', to coin a phrase). I've yet to find a good discussion about how best to go about this; it is an interesting and complex challenge.

A hypothesis can lead to one or more *predictions*, which can be tested. The more specific and novel the predictions that arise from a hypothesis, the more useful that hypothesis is. If a precise prediction is found to be wrong through appropriate experimentation or observation, we can judge the hypothesis to be incorrect i.e. *falsified*. This falsification step usually involves statistical analysis but it not may require it, especially if a single observation is sufficient for falsification (this can be captured using Bayesian philosophy/approaches, but it may not be needed). The proverbial black swan is of course the usual go-to example for the power of a single observation. Real-world examples are harder to come by, but Eddington's observation of light bending around the sun during a solar eclipse (predicted by Einstein's general theory of relativity) might be one; I don't know enough about the details to be sure though.

I've found [Popper's essay on Science as Falsification](https://staff.washington.edu/lynnhank/Popper-1.pdf)<sup>2</sup> to be a short, clear and insightful exposition of this viewpoint. His vision is an excellent goal for science to aspire to, even if it is an incomplete or incorrect description of how science actually functions. It's a strongly contested view, and I'd encourage looking at alternate viewpoints as well.

I find 'theory' and 'testable' are harder to pin down than the other terms. Especially the latter - one can in principle refer to theories or predictions as testable, which muddies the waters somewhat. On this front, Kuhn and Lakatos raised important and interesting ideas about how it is that theories rise and fall. The processes they describe have a strong social dynamic and are much messier than the Popperian falsification of hypotheses described above. Hypotheses that form part of a theory can be falsified while the theory itself survives in some reduced or modified form, for example. Often, the theory is jettisoned only when a substantial portion of its core ideas are falsified or replaced by a theory that improves on it - by making new predictions, or more precise and accurate ones.

---

<sup>1</sup> I think statistics has done science a disservice by causing so much confusion around the term 'hypothesis'. Null hypothesis statistical testing has arguably led to a great deal of poor science in part because people think that they are pursuing some high scientific goal by 'testing hypotheses' even though it's the uninteresting kind of hypotheses.

<sup>2</sup> Popper, K. R. (1963). Science as falsification. Conjectures and refutations, 1(1963), 33-39.

Comment: Are you able to clarify why you think the hypotheses selected for testing are " the uninteresting kind of hypotheses"? What type of hypotheses are the interesting kind of hypotheses in your view?

Comment: @GrahamBornholt In my opinion, $\beta = 0$ (the standard statistical hypothesis tested) is uninteresting in almost all models one encounters. Often, it would be surprising if $\beta$ *was* precisely 0. Interesting and memorable hypotheses are often remembered as theories once they survive serious attempts at falsification and gain support. Darwinian evolution is a fantastic example of this. Another case that I'm less familiar with is the existence of the Higgs boson/field to explain why particles have mass.

Comment: These are some of the greatest cases in science, so perhaps it's not fair to hold every study to that standard. So instead, let me offer a nice example of an interesting hypothesis from my field that does NOT appear to be true. The **burglar alarm hypothesis** tried to explain why some unicellular algae in the ocean are bioluminescent.  This is a puzzle because bioluminescence is complex and costly, and doesn't serve an obvious purpose in these algae. Bioluminescence is often used to attract mates, prey, or organisms that help disperse offspring, none of which applies in these organisms.

Comment: @GrahamBornholt It also attracts attention when that seems to be a bad idea. One curious feature is that it happens when the surrounding water is disturbed. The burglar alarm hypothesis says that this disturbance is often caused by the swimming of the predators of the algae, and that cells flash to attract *the predators of their predators*. In other words, it's like a plant using a literal flashing light to call the attention of a wolf and indicate that there's a tasty deer right there.

Comment: While we haven't fully ruled this hypothesis out, it's not consistent with much else we have learned, and it appears very unlikely that it is true. But it's an appealing and thought-provoking idea, and I commend the people who came up with it. I think this side of science - the creation of good research hypotheses - is woefully neglected, and I partly blame the conflation with statistical hypotheses for this problem.